# How to test if a List has an object with a specific property value

Tags: vb.net

I want to test if there is a class instance with a specific property value.

I know I can iterate through the list to find out. I also know I can use

```
ObjectFound = List.Find(Function(c) c.Property = PropertySearched)
```

How do I test if the ObjectFound was not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IEnumerable.Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) results in a Boolean

```
ObjectFound = List.Any(Function(c) c.Property = PropertySearched)
```